# iMac keyboard not connecting to GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, keyboard, bluetooth, mac

I recently installed Ubuntu on my late 2011 iMac 27'on a separate partition to OSX Mavericks and found after accidentally disabling Bluetooth in Ubuntu and rebooting, my keyboard not being recognized in grub. The first time it automatically booted into Ubuntu but now it is stuck at the OS selection screen and I have no possible way to select an OS.

This is a work computer and is very important so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Gabriel.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting a USB keyboard, booting up as normal, then re-enabling bluetooth.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to get it up and running quite soon and most shops are closed till monday in my town. There arent any possible alternatives?

Comment: I can't really think of any. It seems like you need a working keyboard to get past grub. I presume that you've disabled bluetooth on a hardware level, otherwise I'd suggest booting up with a LiveCD. (It might be worth a shot, but I suspect that bluetooth would still be disabled then.) Can you borrow a USB keyboard from someone? You'll only need it for a few minutes, to re-enable bluetooth, then you can revert to your bluetooth keyboard.